# Can Ba(OH)2 be used for carrying aldol?

Tags: aldol-reaction

I know that aldol reactions require a weak or a moderately strong base for the mechanism to occur and cannizaro happens when a stronger base is used. But my textbook has used Ba(OH)2 as a base in many aldol reactions as a base, which is even stronger than NaOH. Is my textbook in the wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Aldol reaction assumes presence of enolizable hydrogen on one of reactants. Cannizzaro reaction assumes absence of it.

Comment: Barium hydroxide may be a stronger base than NaOH in aqueous, but these aldols are not being done in water. Ba(OH)2 has low solubility in most organic solvents so the aldol reactions occur on the surface of the solid Ba(OH)2.